# jQuery scroll event switching back and forth between if/else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have a column that I want to stick to the top of the page, but once it gets to the point of sticking any further scrolling causes it to jump back and forth between having the added class and not.

```
function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#stick-me').offset().top;
  if (window_top >= div_top) {
    $('#stick-me').addClass('stick');
  } else {
    $('#stick-me').removeClass('stick');
  }
}

$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
```

My intuition tells me it's an issue with the conditional statements, but I'm not sure how else I can structure it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle demonstrating your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add/remove the class as such, simply toggle class. Without seeing your CSS and other JS conflicts all I can do is show you a working example.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/tbdbyxvu/

```
var $window = $(window),
       $stickyEl = $('#the-sticky-div'),
       elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;

   $window.scroll(function() {
        $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

the `#stick-me` element is getting moved when your class 'stick' is applied (as you would want).

When your function runs a second time, `div_top` is now a new (larger) number and your if statement (which proved true the first time) now proves false and removes the class.

In short, your class is being added and removed over and over again.

I would suggest storing #stick-me's original location on page load in a variable `startingPoint` outside of sticky_relocate, then adding/removing the class when scrollTop is greater than `startingPoint`.

```
function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (window_top >= startingPoint) {
    $('#stick-me').addClass('stick');
  } else {
    $('#stick-me').removeClass('stick');
  }
}

$(function () {
    var startingPoint = $('#stick-me').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
});
```